# Pandas extracting data via multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am reading the [following data](https://www.apra.gov.au/annual-fund-level-superannuation-statistics) from a website, into a DataFrame.

I scrub the data using the following script:

```
import pandas as pd

fpath = r'https://www.apra.gov.au/annual-fund-level-superannuation-statistics'
xl_data = pd.read_excel(fpath,sheet_name=['Table 3','Table 9'])
returns = xl_data['Table 3']
returns.columns = returns.loc[2]
returns = returns.iloc[6:,:]
returns['Period'] = pd.to_datetime( returns['Period'])
ror_col = 'One-year\nrate of return'
returns = returns[ returns[ror_col]!='*']
has_returns = returns[ror_col].dropna().index
returns = returns.loc[has_returns].copy()
returns[ror_col]=returns[ror_col].astype(float)
returns_multi_index = returns.copy()
returns_multi_index.index = returns_multi_index[['Period','Fund name']]
returns_multi_index = returns_multi_index[[ror_col]]

returns_multi_index.loc[(slice(None),slice('Alcoa of Australia Retirement Plan')),:] #This line crashes
```

Generally, I want to select all the dates for a certain plan, and all columns.

OR

I want a certain date, but for all plans, and all columns.

I had previously used panels, but with their deprecation I have not yet fully adopted the new multi-index approach.

I am not married to using slices, but was trying to follow th guidance of [this tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers).

The current error I get is:

```
pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_indexer_non_unique (pandas\index.c:5817)()

TypeError: unhashable type
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
returns_multi_index.index = returns_multi_index[['Period','Fund name']]
#Index([              (2018-06-30 00:00:00, 'Alcoa of Australia Retirement Plan'),
#      ...
#      dtype='object', length=4360)
```

It doesn't create a multiindex but rather a regular index of tuples. You should instead use:

```
returns_multi_index.set_index(['Period','Fund name'],inplace=True)
#MultiIndex([('2018-06-30',               'Alcoa of Australia Retirement Plan'),
#           ...
#           names=['Period', 'Fund name'], length=4360)
```

Further, multiIndex slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted, which can be achieved by:

```
returns_multi_index.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: @jason-m Did this answer solve your problem? If so pleae consider accepting it, if not please comment. Thanks.